Equirectangular + Glare: What's the correct workflow?
I've created a scene with generated emissive spheres representing stars. The glare node is used during compositing. I want to render this scene panoramically, for use as an environment texture.
However, the glare node is applied to the final render, with no equirectangular distortion. As a result, using that render as an environment texture causes pinching at the poles.

I've found another StackExchange post regarding the same topic, but none of the answers explain clearly how to work around this problem. How to distort effects with equirectangular projection
I'm assuming the solution is somewhere along the lines of:

Render or bake scene panoramically somehow (cube maps?)
Project render result onto sphere
Render inside of sphere with equirectangular projection

How should this be done?
